# Inserting cursor in middle of Komodo Edit macro

Tags: macros, komodo, komodoedit

I have set up a macro for Smarty in Komodo Edit which adds a `{$|@dumpr}` when I press my specified key binding (which, for info is Ctrl+Alt+P).

What I would like is the cursor to be automatically inserted between the `$` and the `|` so I can type my variable name without having to manually navigate my way in there.

Any help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [currentPos and gotoPos](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macroapi.html#macroapi_scimoz) methods:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); } // bug 67103

var currentPos = komodo.editor.currentPos;
komodo.editor.insertText(currentPos, '{$|@dumpr}');
komodo.editor.gotoPos(currentPos+2);
```